# Using dictionary for multiple identical values one key

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to achieve the following:
Have a dictionary or list with one key ‘date’ with identical values but different values 
Example (process of thought)

```
Data = {}
Data['2017-01-01'] = 123
Data['2017-01-01'] = 321
Data['2017-01-02'] = 123
```

Expected

```
{
    '2017-01-01': 123,
    '2017-01-01': 321,
    '2017-01-02': 21
}
```

Actual result

```
{
    '2017-01-01': 321,
    '2017-01-02': 21
}
```

It might be that I am approaching this issue completely incorrect. Let me describe the scenario.
I scrap data from an HTML site getting dates and purchase values. There can be multiple values on the same day as in my example above. When I have the data, I would like to loop the data and get Date, sum(value), count

Example

```
{
   "record":[
      {
         "Date":"2017-01-01",
         "Value":444,
         "Count":2
      }
   ],
   "record":[
      {
         "Date":"2017-01-02",
         "Value":21,
         "Count":1
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: One of the fundamental aspects of a dictionary is that every key is unique.

Comment: Dictionaries **have unique keys**, that's their *whole point*. Use keys to reference a set or list with values instead.

Comment: Your records example is just a list of records. Use a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: I'd suggest you take time to learn the basics of the technology you are trying to use before asking questions on SO.

Comment: Thanks all, I misused the dictionary. I changed the dictionary to a list that contains dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You could build this dictionary:

```
adict = {
     '2017-01-01': ['321', '123', '223'],
     '2017-01-02': ['144', '445', '222']
}
adict['2017-01-01'].append('224')
```

We initialise a list for the keys value and therefore can store multiple values. We can iterate the values at this location more easily that if we had keys of the same name.. IE:

```
for x in adict['2017-01-01']:
    print x
```